# surfaceView combine with view

Tags: android, view, surfaceview, face-detection, android-asynctask

I am developing game with face recognition,I have a surface-view and View

inside the surface view I capture camera frames and above it have view to recognize the faces and draw them,
the thing is it's working but to slowly, I was thinking about using AsyncTask but am not sure it could help, because as far as i know Views are drawn in UI thread and surface-view are drawn in a separate thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't do the same error as I did with using a [Camera.PictureCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html) instead of a [Camera.PreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html). Methods using the Camera.PictureCallback will capture a full picture of several megapixels, while `Camera.PreviewCallback` methods will return a picture small enough to be used on your screen.

Usually you will not have processing power enough to process a full `Camera.PictureCallback` for each frame.